# How to Turn off Caching of PHP Pages on Server and Browser?

Tags: php, linux, caching, server, debian

I'm not sure where the caching of php pages is coming from. So far I've disabled caching in;

Chrome's Developer Tools> Network > Disable cache;

Debian's \opt\php73\etc\php73.ini with;

```
 opcache.enable=0
 opcache.enable_cli=0
```

I've added to the end of my server entry;

```
fastcgi_cache_bypass $is_args;
  fastcgi_no_cache $is_args;
```

I've got this header at the top of the php script;

```
 header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
```

But I still can't figure out Where the caching is coming from.

Can someone suggest other places I might look?

Comment: How do you know your pages are cached? Does something not work as expected?

Comment: opcache has nothing to do with `pages` ... best turn it back on.

Comment: If you explain the actual problem, we might be able to help you solve that.

Comment: Some code will help, especially on your css and script includes, when you declare them, not the actual source. Likely those are the culprit on cache. If indeed so, you can affix a parameter that changes on each reload. Images too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to stop the caching of your web pages using PHP I use the following code

```
//Minimize caching so admin area always displays latest statistics
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

While nothing is really full proof as many CSS and other JS files are cached independant of the PHP and require a refresh to display once updated there are other ways around this as well.

One example I use is to do a hash of the file (using php):

```
$specific_page = '/assets/javascripts/pages/javascript.js';
if(file_exists($specific_page)) {
    $html .= '<script src="'.$specific_page.'?v='.hash_file('crc32',$specific_page).'"></script>';
}
```

This will keep the cached file until the file is changed.  When the file is changed it changes the hash and thus will find the new updated file (as the URL has technically changed).

Again, nothing is really full proof at preventing caching on the client side.